# Backspace in string formatting while printing to PDF

Tags: c#, string, pdf, formatting, itext

I'm trying to print in PDF two columns of information that contain some strings that the user inputs. This is my code so far:

```
string s = "";
int width = 60 - name.Count(Char.IsWhiteSpace);                                                                  
s = s + string.Format("{0,-" + width +"}", "Name: " + name);
s = s + string.Format("{0,15}","AAA: ");
p1.Add(s);
document.Add(p1);

string p = "";
int width = 60 - surname.Count(Char.IsWhiteSpace);                                                                 
p = p + string.Format("{0,-"+ width +"}", "Surname: " + surname);
p = p + string.Format("{0,15}","BBB: ");
p2.Add(p);
document.Add(p2);

string r = ""; 
int width = 60 - school.Count(Char.IsWhiteSpace);                                                       
r = r + string.Format("{0,-"+ width +"}", "School: " + school);
r = r + string.Format("{0,15}","CCC: ");
p3.Add(r);
document.Add(p3);
```

If the user enters, for example, "John Edward Jr." for name, "Pascal Einstein W. Alfi" for surname and "St. John" for school, then the expected output is something like this:

```
Name: John Edward Jr.________________AAA:

Surname: Pascal Einstein W. Alfi_______BBB:

School: St. John___________________CCC:
```

I suppose the spaces in every string name, surname and school are the problem. How can I deal with this?

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Name: John Edward Jr.__________________AAA:

Surname: Pascal Einstein W. Alfi_______BBB:

School: St. John_______________________CCC:
```

EDIT:

```
int width = 60 - name.Count(Char.IsWhiteSpace);
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: output in my console is correct.

Comment: When I ran your code I got your expected output.

Comment: It's not working for me when I try to print it in a document such as PDF

Comment: Font that not fixed in width my be a problem

Comment: maybe you are not using monospaced font.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

Comment: Have you considered using actual iTextSharp *tables* instead of formatting by spaces?

Comment: No because I'm writing both to pdf and ms word so the problem remains for ms word at the end

Comment: In MS Word you can also use tables to solve the same problem.

Comment: Yes but all in all I'll give myself som time to figure out how to do it in this way

Comment: By the way, [**this image**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OSpm6.png) shows how your expected output looks to me... Another case of layouting with spaces gone wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that we want to render this data in tabular format:

```
public static final String[][] DATA = {
    {"John Edward Jr.", "AAA"},
    {"Pascal Einstein W. Alfi", "BBB"},
    {"St. John", "CCC"}
};
```

There are three ways to achieve this using iText.

**Solution #1: use a table**

Please take a look at the [SimpleTable13](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/alternatives-using-pdfptable#1597-simpletable13.java) example:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setWidthPercentage(50);
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    table.setWidths(new int[]{5, 1});
    table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    table.addCell("Name: " + DATA[0][0]);
    table.addCell(DATA[0][1]);
    table.addCell("Surname: " + DATA[1][0]);
    table.addCell(DATA[1][1]);
    table.addCell("School: " + DATA[2][0]);
    table.addCell(DATA[1][1]);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

We create a table with 2 columns and we add 6 cells. This will result in a table with 2 columns and 3 rows. As we removed the border and as we told the table that the first column should be 5 times as wide as the second column, the result looks like this:

[image]

Advantage: should there be too much text in one of the cells, then the content will automatically wrap and the size of the table will adapt to accommodate the content.

**Solution #2: use tabs**

Please take a look at the [TableTab](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/alternatives-using-pdfptable#1599-tabletab.java) example:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();

    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));

    document.open();

    document.add(createParagraphWithTab("Name: ", DATA[0][0], DATA[0][1]));
    document.add(createParagraphWithTab("Surname: ", DATA[1][0], DATA[1][1]));
    document.add(createParagraphWithTab("School: ", DATA[2][0], DATA[2][1]));

    document.close();
}

public Paragraph createParagraphWithTab(String key, String value1, String value2) {
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.setTabSettings(new TabSettings(200f));
    p.add(key);
    p.add(value1);
    p.add(Chunk.TABBING);
    p.add(value2);
    return p;
}
```

In this example, we create a paragraph for which we define tabs of 200 user units. Now when we add a `Chunk.TABBING`, the content will jump to that position. The result looks like this:

[image]

Disadvantage: when there is too much text in the first column, that text will run into the second column, and a tab will be added at the next 200 user units (could be on the same line, could be on the next line).

**Solution #3: use spaces and a monospaced font**

This is what you're doing, except that you don't use a monospaced font which doesn't give you the result you want.

Please take a look at the [TableSpace](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/alternatives-using-pdfptable#1598-tablespace.java) example:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Document document = new Document();

    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));

    document.open();

    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font font = new Font(bf, 12);

    document.add(createParagraphWithSpaces(font, String.format("%s: %s", "Name", DATA[0][0]), DATA[0][1]));
    document.add(createParagraphWithSpaces(font, String.format("%s: %s", "Surname", DATA[1][0]), DATA[1][1]));
    document.add(createParagraphWithSpaces(font, String.format("%s: %s", "School", DATA[2][0]), DATA[2][1]));

    document.close();
}

public Paragraph createParagraphWithSpaces(Font font, String value1, String value2) {
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.setFont(font);
    p.add(String.format("%-35s", value1));
    p.add(value2);
    return p;
}
```

Now we format the first String so that it always measures 35 characters. The result looks like this:

[image]

Disadvantages: if the text in the first column needs more than 35 characters, it will run through the second column and the text of the second column will be glued to it. You also see that I needed to use a different font. I use [PTMono-Regular](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/fonts/PTM55FT.ttf). Usually, text in a monospaced font takes more space than text in a proportional font. For more info about monospaced fonts read my answer to: [How to set monospaced font by using iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495221/how-to-set-monospaced-font-by-using-itextsharp)

Comment: Thank you for a great answer and explanation. Just a quick question: is it possible to write to table by using indexes, like [0][1] for example

Comment: No, that's not possible. That's what arrays are for.

Comment: There is one more question I am interested in. I can ask you here or I will post it tommorow as new question. The question is about adding cells by going through more than one if-conditions

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - +1 for the `TabSettings` example, and for giving three different answers/options to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the spacing key you use when printing to PDF.
Simply use non-breaking spaces instead (press `Alt`+`<255>`) or you can convert your spaces with the below code:

```
string s = " ";
if(s == " ")
{
 s = "&nbsp;"
}
```

**OR**

use `"My name  is this".Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");`

**Update 2**

Since you are using iText# you can you the API to insert spaces by doing for example:

```
iTextSharp.text.Paragraph s = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(name, font);
s.SpacingAfter = 20;
s.Add("AAA: ");
```

Please let me know if my answer support your question.

Comment: Mentioning MigraDoc is not relevant because A) that was not the question and B) iTextSharp is already Open Source, you can find the source on GitHub.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I approved your proposed edit. thank you. please consider to revevt your down vote,

Comment: I did not downvote, that must have been someone else. However I did flag. I cannot undo a flag. Any SO mods may now ignore my flag because it is no longer relevant after the edit.

Comment: Yes, this was my first thought but in the end, if you have input strings of different lenght, the space between string and AAA: will be different for each line

Comment: you can define a default size and upon the given string define the empty slot then add your "AAA:" string in that way everything is known and can be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this below. It worked for me. you are using (60 - name.size) for name width but you are not using (name.width) for AAA. if you use this then total width will be = (60 - name.size) + name.size = 60. [I think this is what you are wanting.]. good luck.

```
string name = "John Edward Jr.";
        string surname = "Pascal Einstein W. Alfi";
        string school = "St. John";
        string s = "";
        int charWidth = 0;
        int width = 60 - name.Count();
        charWidth = name.Count();
        s = s + string.Format("{0,-" + width + "}" + "{1," + charWidth + "}", "Name: " + name, "AAA: ");
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        s = "";
        width = 60 - surname.Count();
        charWidth = surname.Count();
        s = s + string.Format("{0,-" + width + "}" + "{1," + charWidth + "}", "Surname: " + surname, "BBB: ");
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        s = "";
        width = 60 - school.Count();
        charWidth = school.Count();
        s = s + string.Format("{0,-" + width + "}" + "{1," + charWidth + "}", "School: " + school, "CCC: ");
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: But did you try this while writing to pdf because it's not working when I want to write to pdf