# Implement Tab Space in iText ( PDF )

Tags: android, itext

I have write the code to create the report using itext. For that, I have to add the Content which is like

```
RO              : 1000
Name            : Aldan Rizki Santosa
Date            : Saturday, 13 Mei 2000
```

The code is

```
Paragraph Content = new Paragraph();

Content.add("RO "   + Chunk.TAB + " : " + setReqNo + "\n");
Content.add("Name " + Chunk.TAB + " : " + setName + "\n");
Content.add("Date " + Chunk.TAB + " : " + setDate + "\n");
```

I've done the observation from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [Google](https://google.com/) but I still have not succeeded.

> The results I get from these observations is use `Chunk.TAB` and `Chunk.TAABING` i got it from [iText Chunk](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html) and [iText Tabbing](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext5-building-blocks/tabbing-examples)

but that didn't work, the result is like

```
RO : 1000
Name : Aldan Rizki Santosa
Date : Saturday, 13 Mei 2000
```

Any idea how to reach it ?

I've done the observation from [C# - Backspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480476/backspace-in-string-formatting-while-printing-to-pdf) but it's same not working

[EDIT]

> It turns out the problem is my iText version is an older version
>   (iText 5.3.3) and TabSettings is not working for iText version 5.3.3
>   so i upgraded the iText to version 5.5.10

Comment: You are doing it wrong. See **Solution #2** of my answer to the question [Backspace in string formatting while printing to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480476/backspace-in-string-formatting-while-printing-to-pdf). You forgot to define the tab settings: `p.setTabSettings(new TabSettings(200f));` You also shouldn't use `\n` to mimic different paragraphs. You should use one `Paragraph` object for each paragraph.

Comment: I see that you say that the answer in the duplicate question doesn't work, but it works for me. Which version of iText are you using? Maybe you are using a version that is too old.

Comment: I use itext 5.3.3

Comment: LOL, that version will be 5 years old next Friday. Someone hasn't been maintaining his software.

Comment: You right, i try to define tab setting in my code, 

`Paragraph Content = new Paragraph();
Content.setTabSettings(new TabSettings(200f));` and i got error, The TabSettings got the redcode ( error )

Comment: `TabSettings` probably didn't exist yet in iText 5.3.3. See for instance the changelog for [iText 5.3.4](https://itextpdf.com/changelog/534) where it says *Introduced the concept of TABSPACE in the Chunk class.* That functionality was *under development* five years ago.

Comment: So what's the minimum version for `TabSettings` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154652/discussion-between-aldan-and-bruno-lowagie).